# Echo command with AND operator doesn't exit

Tags: shell, zsh

```
echo hai && echo bye
```

prints

```
hai 
bye
```

while

```
echo hai && echo $?
```

prints

```
hai
0
```

When the first echo command's return value is `0`, how does the echo statement after `AND` operator gets executed? Doesn't quick `AND` come out after seeing the return value `0`?

Comment: 0 means true. && means : execute the next instructions if and ony if the preceding one was true. therefore what you see is normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, also using `zsh`, I have

```
echo hai && echo bye
hai
bye
```

And similarly

```
echo hai && echo %?
hai
0
```

Are you sure that you are seeing `hai` and `bye` on the same line with exactly the commands you have provided here?

In direct answer to your question, an exit status of zero is *success*, so the second statement is executed. (This allows different non-zero exit status values to indicate different errors.)

Comment: does hai and bye come on same line? that is my mistake....

Comment: @MadhavanKumar also for `hai` and `0`?

Comment: They will be on different lines, unless you use `echo -n` to suppress the newline. Perhap something s wrong with your terminal?

Comment: @roaima changed...

Answer (score 23):

Your confusion stems from the fact that many popular languages (especially C-based ones) stop evaluating `&&` sequences when 0 is encountered, because 0 is considered `false` and everything else is `true`. In Bash, however, that's not the case. By convention, in POSIX systems (and all other Unix-like systems), return code 0 is considered `SUCCESS` (there was no error, so nothing is returned) and a non-zero return code is considered `FAILURE`. Every command in Bash, be it an external program such as a C program or a shell builtin, must return a value:

> A *simple command* is a sequence of optional variable assignments
>   followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and
>   terminated  by  a *control operator*.  The first word specifies the
>   command to be executed,    and is passed as argument zero.  The
>   remaining  words  are  passed  as    arguments to the invoked command.
>
> The return value of a *simple command* is its exit status, or
>   128+*n* if the command is terminated by signal *n*.
>
> (...)
>
> Shell
>   builtin commands return a status of 0 (*true*) if  successful,  and
>   non-zero (*false*)  if an error occurs while they execute.  All
>   builtins    return an exit status of 2 to indicate incorrect usage.

A return value is not a Boolean, though. It's a number between 0 and 255:

> The  exit  status  of  an executed command is the value returned by
>   the *waitpid* system call or equivalent function.  Exit statuses fall
>   between    0  and  255, though, as explained below, the shell may use
>   values above    125 specially.  Exit statuses from shell builtins and
>   compound commands    are  also limited to this range. Under certain
>   circumstances, the shell    will use special values to indicate
>   specific failure modes.
>
> For the shell's purposes, a command which exits with a zero exit
>   status    has  succeeded.   **An exit status of zero indicates success. 
>   A non-zero    exit status indicates failure.**  When a command
>   terminates  on  a  fatal signal *N*, bash uses the value of 128+*N* as
>   the exit status.

(Bolding mine.)

When a command reports its return code back to the shell, it's generally enough to check whether the exit code is 0 or not.

Now, the next command in a list glued together with `&&` will be executed only if the previous command returned 0—i.e. `SUCCESS`:

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one or more  pipelines  separated 
>   by
>   the  `&&`  and  `||` control operators, respectively.  AND and OR lists are
>   executed with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
>               command1 && command2
> ```
>
> ***command2* is executed if, and only if, *command1* returns an  exit  status
>   of zero.**

Answer (score 7):

The return value from commands are different from typical boolan values.  0 is success when executing a command, anything else is failure.  && expects 0 to me success here for that reason.